# Within a batch file, how can one break out of nested if statements if one criteria is met, but not the surrounding for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, if-statement

Here's what I have...

```
For /F %%A In ('Type "C:\List.Of.PCs.txt"') Do @(
  Set PC=%%A
  For /F %%B In ('Dir "C:\Users" /B') Do @(
    Set USR=%%B
    If "!USR!" Neq "AAA" (
      If "!USR!" Neq "ABC" (
        If "!USR!" Neq "CDE" (
          If "!USR!" Neq "DEF" (
            [28 more if statements]
            Dir "\\!PC!\C$\Users\!USR!\AppData\Local\Temp\Logs\File.To.Find.Log" >Nul 2>Nul
            If "%ErrorLevel%" Equ "0" Echo File found on !PC! for !USR! >"C:\Results.txt"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The goal is to break out of all those if statements if only one of them is satisfied, then start over with the outer-most for loop. Is this possible? If so, how the heck is that done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you want to perform the command for each user that is not in your exclude list?

Comment: you can use `GOTO` labels to jump out of a `FOR` loop

Comment: @HackingAddict1337. `goto` will break out of the loop entirely, you cannot `goto` inside of of parenthesized code blocks.

Comment: Please provide all of your actual `if` statements, _(if they are all the same `If "!USR!" Neq "something"`, just provide all of the actual `something`'s)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have an exclusion list, so if you only want to exclude certain users, but run the command for the rest, I would do something like this:

```
@echo off
set "exclude=AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF"
For /F %%A In ('Type "C:\List.Of.PCs.txt"') Do @(
for %%I in (%exclude%) do (
  For /F %%B In ('Dir /b "C:\Users"') Do (
    if not "%%B" == "%%I" (
            Dir "\\%%A\C$\Users\%%B\AppData\Local\Temp\Logs\File.To.Find.Log" | findstr /IRC:"File\.To\.Find\.Log" >nul 2>&1
            If errorlevel 0 (Echo File found on %%A for %%B)>>"C:\Results.txt"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**EDIT** as per your comment, look at these examples (and can be run from `cmd`).

```
set "var=123"
if not "%var:~1%" == "1" if not "%var:~-1%" == "2" if not "%var:~1%" == "9" echo %var%
```

The above will print true as none of the positions evaluated is true.
Each `if` statement is evaluated, if any of them are not true, it will perform the task.

but then:

```
if not "%var:~1%" == "1" if not "%var:~-1%" == "3" if not "%var:~1%" == "9" echo %var%
```

Will not perform the `echo` as one of the evaluations was not met. You can place these in any order and it will still not echo as each are evaluated.

Therefore, your code can be something like (Untested):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /F %%A In ('Type "C:\List.Of.PCs.txt"') Do @(
  For /F %%B In ('Dir /b "C:\Users"') Do (
    set "usr=%%B"
    if not "!usr:~1,3!" == "AAA" if not "!usr:~2,4!" == "BBB" if not "!usr:~1,3!" == "CCC" (
            Dir "\\%%A\C$\Users\!usr!\AppData\Local\Temp\Logs\File.To.Find.Log" | findstr /IRC:"File\.To\.Find\.Log" >nul 2>&1
            If errorlevel 0 (Echo File found on %%A for !usr!)>>"C:\Results.txt"
    )
  )
)
```

PS!! `if not "var" == "tes"` is not measure if characters match, where `if 12 equ 12` is mathematical. you cannot perform `if "var" leq "tes` as `var` cannot be `l`ess or `eq`ual to `tes`.

See `if /?` for more on that.

On your last comment. No, it cannot assume if one did not match that the rest wont either. Here's a scenario:

Pete is a user to be excluded, so:

```
if not pete == sam if not pete == pete ...
```

You're expecting it to exit, because `pete` is not `sam`, so it must run the command, however, the next `if` would have matched. So each of the users must me evaluated against all the exclusions..

Comment: Yes, I did think about an exclude list, using another for loop, but some of the excludes are partial pieces of usernames like (If "!USR:~0,3!" Neq "_12") or (If "!USR:~-5!" Neq "_test").

Comment: So then set the variable and stil do `if not "!USR:~0,3!" == "_12" If "!USR:~-5!" Neq "_test"` in a straight line. It will mean that if any of those are true it will do the rest. I will post a simple example in the answer which you can test and see the concept.

Comment: I added the difference to the answer as well for you

Comment: And, does combining all the "if nots" on one line allow that line to break out immediately if one of those if conditions is met...thereby allowing the code to run more quickly?

Comment: Well no. Each user needs to be evaluated against each condition. If it was the other way around where a user needs to be matched and not excluded it will run the command as soon as it found a match.

Comment: Well, just do the `if not` statements, it will work.

Comment: see the final edit I added at the bottom of answer.

Comment: Ahh...so, if I say (If Not "!USR!" == "wow" If Not "!USR:~0,3!" == "txt" If...) and the match happens where the "!USR:~0,3!" actually evaluates to "txt", it would exit that long If evaluation line right at that point, correct?

Comment: Yes!!! but if that match is at the end of the line, it will have to evaluate each of the others before it gets there. but again if that match is right in the beginning, it will exit sooner.

Comment: lol. Ok, so hover over your comment, on the far right (next to the time) a red delete apear. only remove what you feel is relevant to remove though.